# Lua - load properties into table

Tags: properties, lua

I would like to load a config.lua file containing global variables so that I can wrap and then access those variables into a local table.

config.lua looks like this:

```
prop01=value01
prop02=value02
```

script.lua would look like this

```
-- fragment starts --
local config = {
   -- something goes here
}
-- fragment end --

print (config.prop01) -- should print "value01"
print (config.prop02) -- should print "value02"
```

How can I change the "fragment" to get expected printout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the environment when loading the config file.

In lua 5.3 it is done using functions `load` or `loadfile` documented [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load):

```
local config={}
local config_init_fun = loadfile('config.lua',"configuration file",config)
config_init_fun()
```

In lua 5.1 you will need to use `setfenv` function:

```
local config={}
local config_init_fun = loadfile('config.lua',"configuration file")
config_init_fun = setfenv (config_init_fun, config)
config_init_fun()
```

The assignment of setfenv result might be unnecessary but I don't have lua5.1 at hand to verify that.

All that assuming that config.lua is a valid script that is setting some global variables.

Comment: Your solution works for me. I'm using Lua 5.1.5 and confirm that setfenv is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: The remark is not about `setfenv` itself, it is needed without a doubt. What I don't know is whether `setfenv` alters the passed function or creates copy. That is, can `fun=setfenv( fun, env )` be replaced by simply `setfenv( fun, env )`? Probably it can, but I did not test that.